# Не понимаю, как можно исправить ошибки dockle

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Собираю образ с помощью `docker build -t nginx:stable .`
Вот сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable
USER root
WORKDIR /home/

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./start.sh /home/

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y gcc spawn-fcgi libfcgi-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    chmod u-s /bin/su; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/newgrp; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/passwd; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/gpasswd; \
    chmod u-s /bin/umount; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/chfn; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/chsh; \
    chmod u-s /bin/mount; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/expiry; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/chage; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall; \
    chmod g-s /sbin/unix_chkpwd; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /home/; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx; \
    touch /var/run/nginx.pid; \
    chown nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid

USER nginx

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
 CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1

CMD ["sh", "./start.sh"]
```

Потом запускаю проверку с помощью `dockle -ak NGINX_GPGKEY -i CIS-DI-0010 -t 5m nginx:stable`

Вот ее вывод:

```
WARN    - CIS-DI-0001: Create a user for the container
    * Last user should not be root
INFO    - CIS-DI-0006: Add HEALTHCHECK instruction to the container image
    * not found HEALTHCHECK statement
INFO    - CIS-DI-0008: Confirm safety of setuid/setgid files
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/passwd
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chage
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/newgrp
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chsh
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/umount
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chfn
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x sbin/unix_chkpwd
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/mount
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/expiry
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/wall
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/gpasswd
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/su
```

Не понимаю, почему эти ошибки остались. Вроде и пользователя изменил, и разрешения дал, и HEALTHCHECK на месте. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Ну, если вы в команде dockle указали `nginx:stable`, то значит вы и проверяете именно `nginx:stable`, а вовсе не свой образ, видимо?

Comment: Меня очень сильно смущает, что вы собираете образ с опцией `-t nginx:stable` на основе образа `FROM nginx:stable`, попахивает нездоровой рекурсией

Comment: @andreymal если меняю, например, на docker build -t img:new ., то выползает unable to initialize a image struct: failed to initialize source: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving

Comment: Подозреваю, что эта ошибка не имеет отношения к докеру и у вас что-то сломано в системе. Вот этот самый https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ хотя бы в браузере открывается например? (Он должен написать ошибку unauthorized, но открыться хотя бы с ошибкой всё равно должен)

Comment: @andreymal да, открывается с ошибкой unauthorized

Comment: @andreymal перезапустил докер, dockle начал ругаться на другое немного: unable to initialize a image struct: failed to initialize source: reading manifest new in docker.io/library/img: requested access to the resource is denied